# Centering footer text on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hey guys im having an issue here with my footer when resize the screen / on mobile. My footer text is placed to the left and my ul's are maligned. I attached my code bellow, im looking to keep the same layout on desktop but when the screen shrinks have the footer text align center with the layout but keep the same text styling as well so the uls and li's line up with text-align:left;

https://s32.postimg.org/glxnik7gl/footer.png

HTML:

```
<footer>
  <div class="container" id="contact">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="logo-text-footer">Company Logo</span></a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul>Quick Links</ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Services</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul>Address</ul>
        <li>1234 Example Street </li>
        <li>City</li>
        <li>State</li>
        <li>55555</li>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <li>Call: 555-555-5555</li>
        <li>E-Mail: example@gmail.com</li>
        <div class="social-icons">
          <li>Facebook</li>
          <li>YouTube</li>
          <li>Instagram</li>
          <li>Twitter</li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="privacy">
        <p>
          <?php echo date("Y"); ?> Company Name | All Rights Reserved</p>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
/* Footer */
footer {
  height: auto;
  background: #3a526a;
}

footer #contact {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 13em;
}

footer .contact-text {
  position: relative;
  top: 20em;
}

span.logo-text-footer {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
}

footer #contact ul {
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
  padding: 0;
}

footer #contact li {
  color: #fff;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Myriad Pro';
  padding-top: 5px;
}

footer .social-icons li {
  display: inline-block;
}

footer .privacy {
  height: 50px;
  background: #455e76;
}

footer .privacy p {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 50px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-center` class in footer. Change `col-sm-3` class to `col-md-3 col-sm-12` in each div. As this is for mobile view, add following CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  footer {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-brand {float:none;}
}
```

Check [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qxuagax/) here.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can take it from here..i was actually trying to avoid overriding the media queries, I should break that habit huh haha. Can you explain quickly why you chose col-sm-12 for each div? Shouldn't each div I have inside the row equal to 12 total though?

Comment: Oh, I meant where you have used col-sm-12, you need to replace those with 'col-md-3 col-sm-12'. As, in mobile view, each part like 'quick-link' are taking the full width. So, it needs to be col-sm-12.

Comment: col-sm-12 is the full width though, didnt each col have to equal 12 in total? I dint know you can add col-*-12 to each div separately, I thought each div had to equal 12 in total. Such as <div class="col-sm-6">, <div class="col-sm-6"> and thats all you can have since it equals 12?

Comment: As div is a block element, div itself might take the full width. But, still using col-*-12 is a better idea. Also, it works when you make it responsive. See, the there we four columns when it's in large screen, but in small screen, it's single column. How would you get that? If you only put col-sm-3, that'll make 4 columns in all screen (4*3=12). But, when you put 'col-sm-12 col-md-3' - it says in small screen, it'll take full width but in mid/large screen,  there will be 4 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Alignment in bootstrap is very easy so just you know about some class name like `text-center` to make alignment in center position, `text-right` to make alignment in right position, `text-left` to make alignment in left position.

In your code you are using `ul` and `li` but for making responsive design to avoid `ul` and `li` . So you can use always work with only `div`.